# Trying to find certain files recursively and change the filename

Tags: command-line, find, execute-command

I'm trying to search recursively in all subfolders for files with have dots inside their filename and remove the dots (except the last one)

The rename command works on its own, the find command too, but they're not working together:

```bsh
find ./ -type f -execdir rename -n 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)//g' *.txt \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glob in an `-execdir` command won't work, better let `find` search for the files you want and run `rename` only on them:

```bsh
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rename -n 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)//g' {} \;
```

Turns out your `rename` expression doesn't work with paths, try this instead:

```bsh
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rename -n 's:\.(?=[^./]*\.)::g' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get this when trying to execute the command (without -n):

`Can't rename ./test/t.e.s.t.txt /test/test.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think @Henry's regex can be fixed to require no `/` after the `.`: `'s:\.(?=[^./]*\.)::g'`

Comment: Note that you can use `-execdir` in place of `-exec` to prevent `rename` from messing with the whole path, although in this case I'm not sure how much it helps, since `find` will prefix each filename with `./` (I guess a bit, since you can then just replace all dots except the leading one)